# Running Python code using C API, interrupting and resuming

Tags: python, c, multitasking, c-api

From my C program, I'm running a Python script using the Python/C-API.
I use `PyRun_SimpleFile`, which reads the Python script and executes it to the end.

I would like to "interrupt" the Python script when a certain Python command is executed. Let's call it `cwait()`. The control should then return to C which. When the C program decides to do so, it should resume the execution of the Python script where it was interrupted.

Thus I would like to be able to write a Python script something like this:

```
import cwaitmodule
print("hello world")
cwaitmodule.cwait(1000)
print("A second has passed")
for x in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    print(x)
    cwaitmodule.cwait(100)
```

You may call this cooperative multitasking in the sense that either C executes or Python executes.

Note that the C program must be the "master", which reads and executes the Python script. So from the command line, I type something like this:

run_script -p my_script.py

Comment: After you call `cwait()` where should the control return to? The line after `PyRun_SimpleFile` or some other `C_callback_function`?

Comment: The line after `PyRun_SimpleFile`, or whatever `PyRun_*` I end up using.

Comment: Why do you want this? It seems impossible because once `PyRun_SimpleFile` returns, the python interpreter exits (all python variables get lost). Do you need some python variables to survive after `cwait()`?

Comment: The solution will probably not use `PyRun_SimpleFile`, but rather `PyRun_String` or `PyRun_InteractiveOne` to execute one line or statement at a time.

Comment: If _the C program decides_ when the Python script should resume, what's the point of the arguments `1000` or `100`?